# I want to parse this lisk with Jsoup but it fail "https://www.express.pk/world/archives/?page=1"

Tags: jsoup

I want to parse this link // https://www.express.pk/world/archives/?page=1 //
in Jsoup but it fail what is the way to do

Mainactivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private TextView result;


    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run () {
                final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

                try {
                    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.express.pk/world/archives/?page=1/").get();
                    String title = doc.title();
                    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");

                    builder.append(title).append("\n");

                    for (Element link : links) {
                        builder.append("\n").append("").append(link.text());
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    builder.append("Error : ").append(e.getMessage()).append("\n");
                }

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run () {
                        result.setText(builder.toString());
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();

    }
}
```

Activity_main:

```
    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Result ..."
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textSize="17sp"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

This servers has some strange behavior. For given url it returns status 404 which means "Not found" and yet still returns expected content.

Jsoup checks return status, because it gets 404 predicates that content is incorrect, and throws an error. 
To get content from this website you need to disable this default behaviour by setting ignoreHttpErrors flag like this:

```
  Document doc =  Jsoup.connect("https://www.express.pk/world/archives/?page=1/")
            .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
            .get();
```

Comment: ahh... you edited your answer. True. that will work too! +1 from me :)

Answer (score 0):

The server responds with a 404 error code, this is why the normal JSoup get mechanism returns with an exception.

However, you can manage the content of the response of the webserver, if you use the more basic functions of [Connection.Response](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.Response.html)

```
Response response = Jsoup.connect("https://www.express.pk/world/archives/?page=1/").execute();
Document doc = response.parse();
```

You can also get the return code with

```
int statusCode = response.statusCode();
```

Note that I do not have a Java compiler runnig right now, so above code is out of my head and my contain mistakes.